# Ember not posting date attribute

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a `date` attribute on my Ember model:

```
// models/foo.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  startDate: attr('date')
});
```

My component is setting the date in the ISO 8601 format as [is convention](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/Ember.Date.html):

```
// components/date-picker.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
...
picker.on({
  set: function(timestamp) {
    // timestamp.select is a unix timestamp
    var date = new Date(timestamp.select);
    var iso = date.toISOString();       
    self.set('property', iso);
  }
});
...
```

And I can see this reflected in the Ember inspector:

[image: Ember Inspector]

However when Ember posts the data to my backend, the `startDate` is `null`.

Does anyone have an idea why this might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date transform expects your property to be a date object client side, not a string.  It checks when serializing it that it's an instance of Date.

```
serialize: function(date) {
  if (date instanceof Date) {
    return toISOString.call(date);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

You are better off setting the property to the date object, and letting it call `toISOString` when it serializes it to send off to the server.